# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.OgmConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, hibernate-ogm

I am building a project called `Calorie Counter` using Spring, Hibernate OGM and MongoDB. The following is my `HibernateUtil.java`.

```
 package com.myCode.utility;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.OgmConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

import com.myCode.entity.Person;

public class HibernateUtil {
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                OgmConfiguration cfgogm = new OgmConfiguration();
                cfgogm.setProperty(Environment.TRANSACTION_STRATEGY,
                        "{TRANSACTION_STRATEGY}");
                // specify JTA platform
                cfgogm.setProperty(Environment.JTA_PLATFORM, "{JTA_PLATFORM}");
                // configure MongoDB connection
                cfgogm.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider",
                        "mongodb");
                cfgogm.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect",
                        "org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.mongodb.MongoDBDialect");
                cfgogm.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database", "testdb");
                cfgogm.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host", "127.0.0.1");
                cfgogm.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port", "27017");

                // add our annotated class
                cfgogm.addAnnotatedClass(Person.class);
                // create the SessionFactory
                serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                        cfgogm.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
                sessionFactory = cfgogm.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

No error is produced while deploying the war file, but following runtime exception is noted while viewing it on browser.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.OgmConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    com.myCode.utility.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:35)
    com.myCode.service.PersonService.newPerson(PersonService.java:14)
    com.myCode.controller.TestController.showTestPage(TestController.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

For reference, my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myCode</groupId>
    <artifactId>CalorieCounter</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CalorieCounter</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- <finalName>CalorieCounter-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName> -->
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache commons dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mongo db dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Beta7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Beta5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <!-- <version>3.5.1-Final</version> -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the error means that at runtime you are using a different version of Hibernate ORM (probably older), that version does not have the method you are using.

If the WAR does not contain the Hibernate ORM library, it means that the version on the container is different from the one you are using in your pom.